# Removing Google Chrome Borders in Theme

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I was curious if it is possible to remove the borders/border lines on Google Chrome. I currently have a dark theme, and the tabs have a border to them. Here is a screenshot so you understand what I'm referring to: [image]

I've referenced a few of the documentations about [themes](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/themes) and the [manifest.json](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest) file but did not see any solutions mentioned.

So I'm curious if anyone could tell me if there is a property/value I can add to the manifest.json file that controls the borders. Even if I can't remove it entirely, if I can at least adjust the color of the border then I could set it as the same color as the background as sort of a cheating way to hide it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The color is calculated automatically and it's [not customizable](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/themes/theme_properties.h)

Comment: Well that's unfortunate. But thank you @wOxxOm

Answer (score 0):

Set the frame color to white, then load a dark image. Chrome will think you are using a bright background so frames around tabs are going to be dark.

Comment: That does not work. Instead of "frame" it is "toolbar" and even there you only get darker buttons (e.g. reload) if you set the color to "rgb(255, 255, 255)".

Comment: But that just comes from setting a dark background image. No need to edit the colors.

Comment: Yes, and then u will be welcomed with nasty bright borders around tabs, to avoid it u need to change color to something bright. You can't use solid dark color without bright borders (i don't like to call it a "hack") but to get dark background under tabs, color of the frame need to be for an example white, then u have to use dark image as a background of this element too. Chrome doesn't recognize colors from pictures. Is that clear? It works for me.